# How can I add text to an inline tikz pickture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing some icons in latex with tikz picture and right below my icon, I would like to add text like "EXIT" start from position (0,0):

```
\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex] {\draw[line width=3pt] (1,1.2)--(1,1)--(0,1)--(0,2)--(1,2)--(1,1.7); \draw[->, line width=1.5pt] (0.7,1.5)--(1.2,1.5)}
```

How can I do that without using nodes? I am not very comfortable with nodes.

Comment: You should definitely get comfortable with nodes if you're using TikZ. They're the only way to use text in TikZ, and a really important basic building block of the whole framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds text externally, using a stack.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackunder[-25pt]{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex] {\draw[line width=3pt] (1,1.2)--(1,1)--(0,1)--(0,2)--(1,2)--(1,1.7); \draw[->, line width=1.5pt] (0.7,1.5)--(1.2,1.5)}%
}{%
 \tiny Caption text
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there's a way to avoid nodes. The easiest way to add text is using the following code

```
\draw (x-position,y-position) node[position:i.e. above] {Text};
```

I think it's very simple and straightforward.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=3pt] (1,1.2)--(1,1)--(0,1)--(0,2)--(1,2)--(1,1.7);
  \draw[->, line width=1.5pt] (0.7,1.5)--(1.2,1.5);
  \draw (0,0) node[above=0cm, below=0cm,left=0cm,right=0cm] {\footnotesize Exit};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can modify `above, left, right, left` to suit your needs.

Comment: If you only need to place a node, there's no need to use a `\draw` command. You can simply say `\node [<options>] at (<x>,<y>) {<text>};`

Comment: @Jake : In order to get him more comfortable with nodes, since he is get used to using the `draw` command.

Comment: I have a box around Exit every time I use nodes

Comment: @esmitex : Try `\node[draw=none] at (x,y) {text};`

Comment: @Thanos: There's no need for `draw=none` when using the `\node` command: `\node at (x,y) {text};` will not draw a box. The box only appears when you're using `\draw (x,y) node {text};`.

Comment: when I did it, it drew a box